# Schengen visa on transit

Tags: indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas

I'm based in the UK, have a Indian citizenship. I need to travel to Armenia on April 3 and return back to UK on April 6.

There are no non-stop flights as far as I can tell - I need to transit via Europe.

https://www.google.com/travel/flights/search?tfs=CBwQAhoeEgoyMDI0LTA0LTAzagcIARIDTEhScgcIARIDRVZOGh4SCjIwMjQtMDQtMDZqBwgBEgNFVk5yBwgBEgNMSFJAAUgBcAGCAQsI____________AZgBAQ&hl=en&gl=uk&curr=GBP

My understanding is that I'll need a double entry Schengen visa, since I'll be entering the transit country twice? How long does it take to get this visa on average?

Can someone help me understand what are my options here?

Comment: If you can travel without having to clear passport controls, i.e., without landing consecutively in two Schengen-area airports, you may not need a visa.  Only certain Schengen countries require a so-called "airport transit visa" of Indian citizens.  For example, I believe France does not and Germany does, but you should definitely check the latest list before relying on this.